# Encoding and signing transaction with aleth client

Tags: transactions, signature, cpp-ethereum

I am learning aleth client. I want to do two simple steps:

1. encode json to rlp with ./rlp create [...]
2. sign this rlp with ./aleth-key sign  <ma_rlp>
   And I am getting errors in ./aleth-key sign  <ma_rlp>. Errors like: 'invalid transaction format' or 'Actual size: 1, data size: 86'.
   What am i doing wrong?
   My json: ["0x","0x2540BE400","0x0078fca08eacba4f0313e43366e6c3ecb21fb8eb","0xc8","0x5208","0x"]
   Does anybody understand what is going wrong?